# An error occurs while compiling APK by FlashDevelop for Android

Tags: android, air

I have included ane but when I compile my project for android an error occurs.
I am not good at Java and AndroidSDK so please teach me the meanings of this error.

Making apk

> call adt -package -target %TYPE%%TARGET% %OPTIONS% %SIGNING_OPTIONS% "%OUTPUT%" "%APP_XML%" %FILE_OR_DIR% -extdir ane

Error

> dx tool failed:
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Ljp/tjk    /ane/BuildConfig;
>           at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:12
>   3)
>           at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:143)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:301)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:278)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$100(Main.java:56)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:229)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpen
>   er.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.j
>   ava:130)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java
>   :108)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:247)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:183)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:139)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:120)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:89)